# Забрать и записать данные в json , angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Добрый день.Нашел пример телефонной книги созданный с помощью angularjs.

Хотел бы уточнить , как отредактировать scope чтобы данные брались из json файла и в него же потом записывались

```
  $scope.phonebook = [
    {
      name: 'Чапаев Василий Иванович',
      phone: '+123-052-5555-234',
      email: 'vasiliy@chapaes.ru'
    }
  ];
```

http://codepen.io/artemdemo/pen/hkoba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript в целом и angular в частности, не имеет доступа к файловой системе и не могут читать/писать в файлы. Вам нужна серверная часть приложения для реализация этого функционала.